# How to handle a checkbox in react if I want certain checkboxes to already appear checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I have a registration form in which the user can select multiple roles through a checkbox. These roles are saved in a database and this already does it correctly, then I have a modal which is used for the user to edit their roles. In this a checkbox is shown again with the roles that they can select.

What I want to achieve is that when the modal is displayed, the roles that the user already has assigned appear marked in the checkbox. I achieve but this only works when I reload the page. What can I do so that as soon as the modal is displayed, the roles that the user has are already marked without having to reload the page?

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../supabase/client";
//import FormEditRoles from "./FormEditRole";
import RegisterFormUser from "./RegisterFormUser";
import SignOut from "./SignOut";
import TableUser from "./TableUser";

const CrudUser = () => {
  const [db, setDb] = useState({});
  const [dataRol, setDataRol] = useState({});
  const [nameRol, setNameRol] = useState([]);
  const [dataUserRol, setDataUserRol] = useState({});
  const [dataToEdit, setDataToEdit] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  const getAuthenticatedUserData = () => {
    try {
      supabase.auth.getUser().then(async (value) => {
        setUser(value.data.user);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const getUserData = () => {
    try {
      supabase.auth.getUser().then(async (value) => {
        const user = value.data.user;
        const { data } = await supabase
          .from("users")
          .select()
          .eq("email", user.email);
        setDb(data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const getRoles = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await supabase.from("roles").select("*");
      setDataRol(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const getDataTabRolesUser = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await supabase.from("users_roles").select("*");
      setDataUserRol(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserRole = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await supabase
          .from("users")
          .select("roles(nombre)")
          .eq("email", user.email);

        const auxNameRol = [];

        if (data.length > 0) {
          data[0].roles.map((el) => auxNameRol.push(el.nombre));
        }
        setNameRol(auxNameRol);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };
    getUserRole();
  }, [dataUserRol, user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
    getRoles();
    getDataTabRolesUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAuthenticatedUserData();
  }, []);

  const createDataUser = async (data) => {
    try {
      data.user_id = Date.now();
      await supabase.from("users").insert({
        user_id: data.user_id,
        email: user.email,
        nombres: data.nombres,
        apellidos: data.apellidos,
        fecha_nacimiento: data.fecha_nacimiento,
        is_active: true,
      });
      console.log("Register added successfully");
      setDb([...db, data]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  const createRolesUser = (data) => {
    data.roles.map(async (el) => {
      await supabase
        .from("users_roles")
        .insert({ user_id: data.user_id, rol_id: el });
      setDataUserRol([...dataUserRol, data]);
    });
  };

  const deleteDataUser = async (id) => {
    let isDelete = window.confirm("Are you sure to delete your data?");
    if (isDelete) {
      try {
        await supabase.from("users_roles").delete().eq("user_id", id);
        await supabase.from("users").delete().eq("user_id", id);

        let newData = db.filter((el) => el.user_id !== id);
        setDb(newData);

        console.log("The record was deleted");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  const updateDataUser = async (data, updateFields) => {
    const { error } = await supabase
      .from("users")
      .update(updateFields)
      .eq("user_id", data.user_id);

    let newData = db.map((el) => (el.user_id === data.user_id ? data : el));
    setDb(newData);

    if (error) throw error;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-1-2">
        <RegisterFormUser
          data={dataRol}
          userData={db}
          createDataUser={createDataUser}
          createRolesUser={createRolesUser}
          dataToEdit={dataToEdit}
          updateDataUser={updateDataUser}
          setDataToEdit={setDataToEdit}
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <TableUser
          dataUser={db} 
          nameRol={nameRol}
          setDataToEdit={setDataToEdit}
          deleteDataUser={deleteDataUser}
          dataRol={dataRol}
          setDataUserRol={setDataUserRol}
          dataUserRol={dataUserRol}
        />
        <SignOut />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrudUser;
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { supabase } from "../supabase/client";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import AvatarUser from "./AvatarUser";

const initialForm = {
  user_id: null,
  nombres: "",
  apellidos: "",
  fecha_nacimiento: "",
  avatar: "",
  roles: [],
};

function RegisterFormUser(props) {
  //Props
  const {
    data,
    userData,
    createDataUser,
    createRolesUser,
    dataToEdit,
    updateDataUser,
    setDataToEdit,
  } = props;

  //States
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [selectedRoles, setSelectedRoles] = useState([]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const getUserData = () => {
    supabase.auth.getUser().then(async (value) => {
      setUser(value.data.user);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

  //Set form Values from dataToEdit
  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataToEdit) {
      setForm(dataToEdit);
    } else {
      setForm(initialForm);
    }
  }, [dataToEdit]);

  //Redirect to signin if not logged in
  useEffect(() => {
    supabase.auth.getUser().then((value) => {
      if (!value.data.user) {
        navigate("/signin");
      }
    });
  }, [navigate]);

  //Handle form input changes
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  //Handle form submit
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (form.user_id === null) {
      createDataUser(form);
      setMessage("Register added successfully");
      setResponse(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setResponse(false);
      }, 3000);
      setTimeout(() => {
        createRolesUser(form);
      }, 200);
    } else if (form.user_id !== null) {
      updateDataUser(form, {
        nombres: form.nombres,
        apellidos: form.apellidos,
        fecha_nacimiento: form.fecha_nacimiento,
      });
    }
    handleReset();
  };

  //Handle form reset
  const handleReset = (e) => {
    setForm(initialForm);
    setDataToEdit(null);
  };

  //Handle select changes
  const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    const roleId = parseInt(e.target.value, 10); // da el id del rol seleccionado 12 , 13, 14

    if (e.target.checked) {
      setSelectedRoles([...selectedRoles, roleId]);
      form.roles = [...selectedRoles, roleId];
      //console.log(selectedRoles);
    } else {
      setSelectedRoles(selectedRoles.filter((id) => id !== roleId));
      form.roles = selectedRoles.filter((id) => id !== roleId);
      //console.log(form.roles)
    }
  };

  //Handle seleccion pictures
  const handleSelectPicture = async (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
      .from("avatars")
      .upload(user.id + "/" + uuidv4(), file);

    if (data) {
      console.log("success");
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Additional data</h1>
      {dataToEdit || userData.length <= 0 ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h3>{dataToEdit ? "Edit" : "Add"}</h3>
          <label htmlFor="nombres">Name </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="nombres"
            name="nombres"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={form.nombres}
            placeholder="Write your Name"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="apellidos">Last names </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="apellidos"
            name="apellidos"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={form.apellidos}
            placeholder="Write your last name"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="fecha_nacimiento">Birthdate </label>
          <input
            type="date"
            id="fecha_nacimiento"
            name="fecha_nacimiento"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={form.fecha_nacimiento}
          />
          <br />
          {!dataToEdit ? <p>Select your role:</p> : null}
          {!dataToEdit ? (
            data.length > 0 ? (
              data.map((el, index) => (
                  <div key={index} className="inline-role">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={`role-${el.roles_id}`}
                      value={el.roles_id}
                      name={el.nombre}
                      checked={selectedRoles.includes(el.roles_id)}
                      onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={`role-${el.roles_id}`}>{el.nombre}</label>
                  </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <p>Loading...</p>
            )
          ) : null}
          <br />
          <br />
          <label htmlFor="avatar">Upload an avatar: </label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="avatar"
            name="avatar"
            accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
            onChange={handleSelectPicture}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <AvatarUser dataToEdit={dataToEdit} userData={userData} />
          <input type="submit" value={dataToEdit ? "Edit" : "Add Data"} />
          <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onClick={handleReset} />
        </form>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h3>Yor data</h3>
          <AvatarUser dataToEdit={dataToEdit} userData={userData} />
        </>
      )}

      {response && <p>{message}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegisterFormUser;
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { supabase } from "../supabase/client";

const initialForm = {
  roles: [],
};

const FormEditRoles = ({ dataUser, dataRol, setDataUserRol, dataUserRol }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState(initialForm);
  const [selectedRoles, setSelectedRoles] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState();
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadSelectedRoles = async () => {
      const { data: userRoles } = await supabase
        .from("users_roles")
        .select("rol_id")
        .eq("user_id", dataUser[0].user_id);

      const selectedRoles = userRoles.map((r) => r.rol_id);
      setSelectedRoles(selectedRoles);
    };
    if (dataUser && dataUser.length > 0) {
      loadSelectedRoles();
    }
  }, [dataUser]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    const roleId = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);

    if (e.target.checked) {
      setSelectedRoles([...selectedRoles, roleId]);
      setForm({ ...form, roles: [...selectedRoles, roleId] });
    } else {
      setSelectedRoles(selectedRoles.filter((id) => id !== roleId));
      setForm({
        ...form,
        roles: selectedRoles.filter((id) => id !== roleId),
      });
    }
  };

  const updateRolesUser = async () => {
    const { data: userRoles } = await supabase
      .from("users_roles")
      .select("rol_id")
      .eq("user_id", dataUser[0].user_id);

    //Gets the IDs of the roles to be removed
    const rolesToDelete = userRoles.filter(
      (r) => !form.roles.includes(r.rol_id)
    );

    //Removes roles that are no longer selected by the user
    for (const role of rolesToDelete) {
      await supabase
        .from("users_roles")
        .delete()
        .eq("user_id", dataUser[0].user_id)
        .eq("rol_id", role.rol_id);
    }

    //When removing any role we update the data
    let newData = dataUserRol.filter(
      (el) => el.user_id !== dataUser[0].user_id
    );
    setDataUserRol(newData);

    //Gets the IDs of the roles to be add
    const rolesToAdd = form.roles.filter(
      (r) => !userRoles.some((ur) => ur.rol_id === r)
    );

    for (const roleId of rolesToAdd) {
      await supabase
        .from("users_roles")
        .insert({ user_id: dataUser[0].user_id, rol_id: roleId });
    }

    setDataUserRol([...dataUserRol, dataUser]);
    setMessage("Roles actualizados exitosamente");
    setResponse(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setResponse(false);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Edit roles</h3>
      {dataRol.length > 0 ? (
        dataRol.map((el, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="inline-role">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={`role-${el.roles_id}`}
              value={el.roles_id}
              name={el.nombre}
              checked={selectedRoles.includes(el.roles_id)}
              onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
            />
            <label htmlFor={`role-${el.roles_id}`}>{el.nombre}</label>
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
      <button onClick={updateRolesUser}>Guardar</button>
      {response && <p>{message}</p>}
    </>
  );
};

export default FormEditRoles;
```

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what the issue is, but you could look into https://github.com/psteinroe/supabase-cache-helpers to make this easier.

Comment: The problem is the following: in the modal, the checkboxes of the roles appear and when the modal is displayed, the checkboxes of the roles that the user already has should appear checked, but they don't appear until I reload the page.